# Expected parameter scala.Option<Timestamp> vs. Actual argument Timestamp

Tags: scala, timestamp

This is probably a very silly question, but I have a case class which takes as a parameter Option[Timestamp]. The reason this is necessary is because sometimes the timestamp isn't included. However, for testing purposes I'm making an object where I pass in

```
Timestamp.valueOf("2016-01-27 22:27:32.596150")
```

But, it seems I can't do this as this is an actual Timestamp, and it's expecting an Option.

How do I convert to Option[Timestamp] from Timestamp. Further, why does this cause a problem to begin with? Isn't the whole benefit of Option that it could be there or not?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In a strictly typed language such as Scala, type `T` and type `Option[T]` are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option indicates the possibility of a missing value, but you still need to construct an `Option[Timestamp]` value. There are two subtypes for Option - `None` when there is no value, and `Some[T]` which contains a value of type `T`.

You can create one directly using `Some`:

```
Some(Timestamp.valueOf("2016-01-27 22:27:32.596150"))
```

or `Option.apply`:

```
Option(Timestamp.valueOf("2016-01-27 22:27:32.596150"))
```